# How to use an atom to update a map's state?

Tags: clojure

I want to create a function that holds the frequencies of strings I deem as spam. I'm trying to use an atomic map that can be updated as I give the map a new string.

**Desired Behavior**

```
user> (train-word spam "FREE")
{"FREE": 1}
user> (train-word spam "FREE")
{"FREE" : 2}
user> (train-word spam "MONEY")
{"FREE" : 2 "MONEY" : 1}
```

So far I have tried

```
(def spam (atom {}))
(defn train-word [m word]
  (swap! update-in m [word]
                 (fn [old] (inc (or old 0)))))
```

but that produces an error:

```
clojure.lang.Atom cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Associative  clojure.lang.RT.assoc (RT.java:702)
```

I'm new to Clojure so I did a quick prototype in Python

```
from collections import defaultdict
spam = defaultdict(int)
def train_word(word, spam):
        spam[word] += 1
```

What is the idiomatic way to manage state using an atom to update current values as well as add new ones? Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, check out [`fnil`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/fnil). `(fnil inc 0)` is a little nicer than `(fn [old] (inc (or old 0)))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just need to pass the atom before the function in the call to `swap!`.

```
user> (def spam (atom {}))                                                        
#'user/spam 
user> (defn train-word [m word]  
        (swap! m update-in [word]  
               (fn [old] (inc (or old 0)))))                                      
#'user/train-word 
 user> (train-word spam "FREE")                                                    
{"FREE" 1}
```

`swap!` constructs the function call by:

- Making a list out of everything after it's first argument,
  `(update-in [word] (fn [old] (inc (or old 0)))`
- Getting the current value of the atom in it's first argument,
  `@m`
- Insert that value as the second item in this list (just after the function name)
  `(update-in @m [word] (fn [old] (inc (or old 0)))`
- Evaluate this list:
  `{"FREE" 1}`
- put the result back in the atom.